# Is there a way to rewrite all relative URL:s when inserting a HTML fragment in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, relative-url

I'm loading a HTML fragment into a page using a jQuery AJAX call. The fragment is loaded from a separate directory on the server and I want to be able to reuse it (with its links to scripts and images) in different locations.

Is there a safe way using JavaScript/jQuery to translate all relative URL:s in a page - relative to where the HTML fragment was loaded from - before inserting it into the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to modify the `href` attribute of every link, you could do...

```
$(document.links).attr('href', function(index, href) {
    return window.location.pathname + '/' + href;
});
```

Comment: I was hoping someone had created a plugin to do this in a safe manner, checking that URL:s are relative, updating all known URL-related attributes and so on. Guess I'll have to roll my own.

Comment: well, the check is easily done be some simple regex. What do you mean with URL related attributes?